# using a pushbutton's call back in an other callback in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have two push buttons in my MATLAB GUI. I am trying to recognize a push button in button1's callback function and do something with regard to which button was pressed. I have tried to use button group and put all my buttons in that group. It seems as if there is no code when any of these push buttons is clicked. Why?

Here is my code:

```
function uibuttongroup1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject,eventdata)  
    switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag') % Get Tag of selected object.  
    case 'notSimul'   
          disp('notSimul clicked')   
    case 'simul'  
        % Code for when radiobutton2 is selected.  
    case 'stopTest'  
        % Code for when togglebutton1 is selected.  
    case 'start'  
        % Code for when togglebutton2 is selected.  
    % Continue with more cases as necessary.  
    otherwise  
        % Code for when there is no match.  
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code assigning the tags to the items, and adding the callbacks to the buttons?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the switch statement and looking at what the NewValue Tag is?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly that you placed a push button in a button group, the answer is it would not work because button group is supposed to be composed of only toggle button and radio button. When I tried putting a push button in a button group, nothing would happen, just as you described.